# Nagios password in resource.cfg

Tags: monitoring, nagios

in resource.cfg i'm storing the password for mysql nagios user.
How can I encrypt the password in resource.cfg ?

Answer (score 0):

*You can't*, that is why your resource.cfg file should have permissions settings that make it unreadable by anyone except by your nagios user.

Why are you storing the password in there? You shouldn't have to unless you're doing something unique.